# $\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n}|^{2} \leq 1 \end{align}$ when $ |\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} z^{n}| \leq 1 $ for $|z| \leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} z^{n} \end{align}$ be a complex power series with radius of convergence greater than $1$ and also assume that $\begin{align} |\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} z^{n}| \leq 1 \end{align}$ for $|z| \leq 1$. Then $\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n}|^{2} \leq 1 \end{align}$

I tried doing the following and reached up to the convergence of $\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n}|^{2} \end{align}$

Since the radius of convergence is greater than $1$, $(a_{n}r^{n})$ is bounded for $r > 1$. Then $|a_{n}r^{n}| \leq M$ for some $M > 0$. This gives $\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n}| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{M}{r^{n}} \end{align}$, by comparison test  $\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n}| \end{align}$ converges. Hence $\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n}|^{2} \end{align}$ converges. Hope till now is fine.

I am stuck at showing that $\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n}|^{2} \leq 1 \end{align}$. Give me a simplest possible method. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know contour integration ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe No

Comment: Ok I added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f : [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $$f : t \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n e^{int}$$

For every $t \in [0,2\pi]$, one has
$$|f(t)|^2 = f(t) \overline{f(t)} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} a_n \overline{a_m} e^{i(n-m)t}$$

Integrating this equality over $[0,2\pi]$, you get
\begin{align*}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)|^2 dt &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} a_n \overline{a_m} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n-m)t} dt \\  &= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} a_n \overline{a_m} 2\pi \delta_{n,m} \\&=  2\pi \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n \overline{a_n}  \\ &=  2\pi \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} |a_n|^2 
\end{align*}
But by assumption,  $\displaystyle|f(t)| = \left| \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n e^{int}\right| \leq 1$, so $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)|^2 dt \leq 2\pi$, which gives
$$2\pi \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} |a_n|^2  \leq 2\pi$$

and you are done.